# Java HtmlUnit onchange event not fired

Tags: java, dom-events, htmlunit, apache-commons

I use HtmlUnit to fill form.
I have a select `SELECT_A`. After selecting option the additional elements must appear in the page. But it's not working! I simulate Firefox 3.6.

What do you think?

I tried to use `NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()` but it does not help.

Comment: See FAQ: [The "onchange" event doesn't fire after a call "sendKeys"](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_The_%22onchange%22_event_doesn%27t_fire_after_a_call)

WebDriver leaves the focus in the element you called "sendKeys" on. The "onchange" event will only fire when focus leaves that element. As such, you need to move the focus, perhaps using a "click" on another element.

Answer (score 5):

One note: fireEvent should be called with `"change"` parameter, not `"onchange"`. Or `fireEvent(Event.TYPE_CHANGE);` is even better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `fireevent("EventName")` and pass eventname as a paramenter:

```
HtmlSelect fromselect = form.getSelectByName("droplist");
fromselect.fireEvent("onchange");
```